# Cannot set image in NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimageview

I have a little piece of program to display an image in an Image-well. I've being testing around but there's nothing shows up on the screen. Appreciate any one can help.

.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSImageView *myImageView;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView *myImageView;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString * filePath = @"haha.png";  // the pic file that I added into the project
    NSImage * aImage = [NSImage imageNamed:filePath];

    if(aImage)
    {
        NSLog(aImage.name);
        NSLog(@"size %f %f",aImage.size.width,aImage.size.height);
        //both of the NSLogs work but the Image-well shows blank            
        [myImageView setImage:aImage];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: These kinds of problems are almost always related to the `IBOutlet` connection not being connected.  When you look at the `IOOutlet` in the header file is the circle "filled" in the lefthand margin?

Comment: Alternatively the image `haha.png` might not be set in the project correctly.  Add an `else` clause to that `if` statement with `NSLog(@"Image not set!");`.

Comment: check the target membership of the image  in inspector panel

Comment: yes the IBOutlet circle's filled and the NSLogs for Img name and size feedback all right. I 'll check the membership of the img.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

You have to use UIImageView in place of NSImageView.

Comment: How do you know?  He hasn't stated the OS has he?  In fact he's included `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` so he's most certainly using OSX!

Comment: u'r right buddy. sure it's osx..but can anybody figure out where the weird problem is?thx

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
NSImage * aImage = [NSImage imageNamed:filePath]
```

**to**

```
NSImage * aImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: What difference will that make?

Comment: @trojanfoe:imageNamed does not accept a full path to the image file. it only accepts a filename and then looks for an image with that filename in the application's main bundle.on the other hand imageWithContentsOfFile expects a full or partial path to the file.

Comment: So I guess `imageNamed:` is more appropriate here, the file path being `@"haha.png"`...

Comment: so it may be the possibility that image file not found in the application's bundle

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the png file's not found in the application's bundle. But the confusing thing is that both the NSlog functions ('NSLog(aImage.name) and NSLog(@"size %f %f",aImage.size.width,aImage.size.height)').
 are working and feedbacking.

Here is how I added the png image. i created a new group folder called 'Resources', and then right clicked and added the prepared photo. Not sure if anything wrong i was doing here.

I finally figured it out. Just implly added a 'self' ahead to 'myImageView set Image:aImage'. like [self.myImageView setImage:aImage];

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue too where I added an image to the `Assets.xcassets` folder, but the image would not appear. The issue turned out to be a format issue, I had specified `box.png` as the image was exported as a `PNG` image. However my Mac app didn't recognise it (for whatever reason). So I removed the `.png` from the string name:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:@"box"]
```

For some reason, the image I had made was not recognised as a `PNG` image. It doesn't matter though, because as per the [Apple dev docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-imagenamed), you don't need to specify the file format for `PNG` images:

> For PNG images, you may omit the filename extension. For all other
>   file formats, always include the filename extension.